# Setting the bracket $ \{ $ only on one side!

Tags: brackets

So I wanted to have a Bracket `$ \{ $` just on one side, but when I plug in a code like the following, LaTeX always says something is wrong. The function looks perfectly normal in the document, but it creates problems with the code. Once I put a bracket on the right side as well, LaTeX doesn't complain anymore!
Problematic code:

```
\begin{align}
    C_\theta (\textbf{L}(L_1)) - C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)) \\
    \left\{\begin{array}{l} = \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] \mbox{ if $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1) >0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)>0)$} \\ \leq \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] \mbox{ if $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1) >0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)=0)$} \end{array}\right
\end{align}
```

Not problematic code:

```
\begin{align}
    C_\theta (\textbf{L}(L_1)) - C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)) \\
    \left\{\begin{array}{l} = \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] \mbox{ if $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1) >0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)>0)$} \\ \leq \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] \mbox{ if $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1) >0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)=0)$} \end{array}\right
\end{align}
```

Can someone help please!

Comment: Use the `cases` environment. You seem to be missing the delimitor for `\right`, it should be `\right.` in your case. But using the `cases` env is much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it. Note that your `not problematic code` has the same problem, you need `\right.`  (note the dot) to get an empty auto scaled fence.

It's a lot easier to just use the `cases` env:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \MoveEqLeft C_\theta (\textbf{L}(L_1)) - C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2))
  \\
  &
  \begin{cases} = \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] & \text{if
      $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1) >0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)>0)$}
    \\
    \leq \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] & \text{if
      $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1) >0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)=0)$}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful!!!

Answer (score 2):

You're telling LaTeX to put a right delimiter with `\right`, but you're not actually specifying one --- put a `.` (i.e. write `\right.`) for an "empty" delimiter:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    C_\theta (\textbf{L}(L_1)) - C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)) \\
    \left\{\begin{array}{l}
        = \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] \mbox{ if $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1) >0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)>0)$}    \\
        \leq \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] \mbox{ if $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1) >0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)=0)$}
    \end{array}\right.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

That said, @daleif's comment is correct, you're likely better off using the `cases` environment --- or use `cases*` (from `mathtools`), which also puts the second part of each case (the condition) in text mode automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    &C_\theta (\textbf{L}(L_1)) - C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)) \nonumber \\
    &\qquad \begin{cases*}
        {} = \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]]    & if $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1)) > 0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)) > 0$ \\
        {} \leq \theta[E(L_1)-E[L_2]] & if $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_1)) > 0$ and $C_\theta(\textbf{L}(L_2)) = 0$
    \end{cases*}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've tried to improve formatting here a bit as well, but there's still (much) room for further improvement.

I've also used `\nonumber` to suppress the numbering on the first part of the multi-line equation, and put empty groups `{}` before the (in)equality signs in the two cases; this improves spacing, as these two are what's known as binary operators in TeX/LaTeX parlance: they expect something on either side.

Finally, I've fixed the parentheses in the conditions for your two cases. (I hope I got these right.)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now without a problem!

Comment: @LVWL You're welcome --- glad to have been able to help!